# Missing Xcode dependency: Python module "six"

Tags: python

I've installed Python module "six" and it prints the same error:
[I've installed and i get the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JWRW.png)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Please run this 2 line of commend

```
brew reinstall python@2
pip install six
```

Then

```
pip install six
```

Make sure you have downloaded brew